# Removing text above real content of CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV whose author, annoyingly enough, has decided to 'introduce' the file before the contents themselves. So in all, I have a CSV that looks like:

```
This file was created by XXXXYY and represents the crossover between YY and QQQ. 
Additional information can be found through the website GG, blah blah blah...

Jacob,   Hybrid
Dan,  Pure
Lianne,   Hybrid
Jack,  Hatchback
```

So the problem here is that I want to get rid of the first few lines before the 'real content' of the CSV file begins. I'm looking for robustness here, so using Streamreader and removing all content before the 4th line for example, is not ideal (plus the length of the text can vary).

Is there a way in which one can read only what matters and write a new CSV into a directory path?

Regards,
genesis

(edit - I'm looking for C sharp code)

Comment: Will there always be blank line between the introduction and the data?   You could break on the blank line instead of the line count.

Comment: if not , you can't , because text, text will be parsed in csv wahtever text is

Comment: If header has arbitrary structure, there can't be 100% robust algorithm.

Comment: unless names are known and in a list

Comment: Yes, there will be a blank line between I believe. Could someone provide me with C sharp code to do so?

Comment: you should be sure. Because if a comment is a blank line , you will not have robust code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the files you have to parse. You need to look for a reliable pattern that distinguishes data from comment.

In your example, there are some possibilities that might be the same in other files:

- there are 4 lines of text. But you say this isn't consistent across files
- The text lives may not contain the same number of commas as the data table. But that is unlikely to be reliable for all files.
- there is a blank/whitespace only line between the text and the data.

  - the data appears to be in the form word-comma-word. If this is true it should be easy to identify non data lines (any line which doesn't contain exactly one comma, or has multiple words etc)

You may be able to use a combination of these heuristics to more reliably detect the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could scan by line (looking for the \r\n) and ignore lines that don't have a comma count that matches you csv.

You should be able to read the file into a string pretty easily unless it is really massive.

e.g.

```
var csv = "some test\r\nsome more text\r\na,b,c\r\nd,e,f\r\n";
var lines = csv.Split('\r\n');
var csvLines = line.Where(l => l.Count(',') == 2);
// now csvLines contains only the lines you are after
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    List<string> info = new List<string>();

    int counter = 0;

// Open the file to read from.
    info = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

// Find the lines up until (& including) the empty one
    foreach (string s in info)            
    {
        counter++;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            break; //exit from the loop
    }

// Remove the lines including the blank one.
    info.RemoveRange(0,counter);
```

Something like this should work, you should probably put some tests in to make sure counter is not > length and other tests to handle errors.

You could adapt this code so that it just finds the empty line number using linq or something, but I don't like the overhead of linq (Yeah ironic considering I'm using c#).

Regards,
Slipoch

Comment: If the downvoters could explain what I did wrong please, I would appreciate it, I wrote this code while falling asleep as I restored an OS.